# Array returns 43 instances of the same row - CodeIgniter PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**We have tables** (details omitted):

```
project {
    projectID,
    addressID
}

address {
    addressID,
    postcode,
    streetName,
    buildingNumber
}
```

And a query to **return the row of the address of the project**.

```
   $this->db->select('a.postcode, p.projectID, p.addressID');
   $this->db->from('address AS a , project as p');
   $this->db->join('project', 'p.addressID = a.addressID');
   $this->db->where('p.projectID', $projectID);

   /* RETURNS SEVERAL INSTANCES OF THE SAME ROW! ... */

   $projectAddress = $this->db->get()->result_array();
   echo sizeof($projectAddress).' -- ';
   print_r($projectAddress[0]['postcode']);
```

We have checked the database and it only contains the one projectID in the project table and the one address record with that projectID. There absolutely cannot be more addresses per project because we have accounted for this in the database.

**Output:**

```
43 -- PA73 6LT
```

**NOTE:** we know we can limit the result set to be one row, but we're curious as to why it's returning this arbitrary number - 43.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You duplicate join, try this:

```
$this->db->select('a.postcode, project.projectID, project.addressID');
$this->db->from('address AS a');
$this->db->join('project', 'project.addressID = a.addressID');
$this->db->where('project.projectID', $projectID);
```